# How to fire trigger after all records inserted?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL server, when does a trigger get fired?

The problem is, I have a table where 45,000 records are going to be inserted.
And I want to copy all 45k records to other tables. 
But I don't want the trigger to run on every insert, i.e 45000 times trigger.

My trigger is basically copying record from TableA to TableB.

Trigger:

```
Create trigger tri_1
on TableA
after insert
as 

Begin 

Insert into TableB (ID,Name,Others)
select ID,Name,Others from TableA
inner join inserted
on inserted.ID = TableA.ID

End
```

The above is just the template of my trigger.

Also, I have a question, the trigger mentioned above, how is it working? like firing for each row or after all insert is done?

Comment: Is it not possible to just use SELECT * INTO new_table FROM old_table ?

Comment: Well, that is the thing that confusing me a bit. I wrote this trigger assuming that, bulk insert of 45K records means 45K insert statements. I did it to avoid repeating data because I will be using * (that mean all records, new entered and old ones)

Comment: @stefan if i use your query, suppose 40K records are inserted in my table, if the trigger fires after, lets say, inserting 200 records, the next time the trigger fire.. it will again copy the older 200 records and new 200 records... 
So in this case I need to be sure that trigger is fired only after all 40K are inserted

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you want to copy (the contents of) a table into a new table.  For this purpose, I'd not use a trigger.  I'd just SELECT everything I need from the old table, and "stick" the result set it into the new table (as it were). I've written a little example (notice: there's only one CREATE TABLE ...)  http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=0db70a850482616710307ae537ccd1f6

Comment: no, actually we are getting data from SAP, so when data is inserted in TableA, we need it to be copied in TableB, thats why trigger needed!

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server, the trigger is fired when the `insert` statement is completed.

In some databases, the trigger is executed for each row inserted (in those databases `for each row` is often part of the syntax).  By contrast, SQL Server keeps track of the changed rows, which is why they are stored in table-like structures, `inserted` and `deleted` -- and it is a mistake to assume that these contain only one row.

Comment: so that means trigger will be fired for like 45000 times, right? cause 45000 records will be inserted all at once

Comment: @Sobmac . . . If you have 45,000 inserts, then the trigger will be called 45,000 times.  If you have one insert with 45,000 rows, it will be called once.

Comment: Data will be received from SAP to our table, so I dont know actually how internally sql server approaches the received data, 45k records will be inserted all at once in Bulk? or perform 45k separate inserts?

Comment: @Sobmac . . . Put the data into a temporary table and use `insert . .  select . . . from #temptable`.